# Enable pagespeed_module in Godaddy’s Deluxe Linux Hosting

Tags: htaccess

I try to enable pagespeed_module in Godaddy’s Deluxe Linux Hosting, the entire .htaccess is as below,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 ## Forward non www to www
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

 ## remove the display of .php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule pagespeed_module>
 ModPagespeed on
 ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache
</IfModule>
```

I have then curl -D -http://ww.thedomain.com but it only show Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev

What are the correct way to enable pagespeed_module in Godaddy’s Deluxe Linux Hosting ? Or how do I debug the problem ?

Comment: This is shared hosting. Have you confirmed that you have privilages to install the module and if not have you contacted their support to enable the module/request the module to be installed?

Comment: @Peter It is supported, though offered as a _beta_. Looks like you've go the right _.htaccess_ code from their support docs [here](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6432/which-mod_pagespeed-functions-do-you-support). You might need to restart the server - look under `System Processes` if you have their in-house control panel. As I remember, if you have an SSL with a dedicated IP address, there was a conflict that prevented PageSpeed from running. I'd suggest contacting their Hosting Department if the restart doesn't work. Let us know what you figured out.

Comment: @Peter Did you figure anything out on this?

Comment: @dan no luck with godaddy yet. Just recently Godaddy updated the apache and php, will try to contact them on this.